# Spring mongo and operator on same field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to create and Operator query with array values. My code is

```
String[]={"abc","pqr",xyz};

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();       
for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
    criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("attribute").regex("^" + splited[i], "i"));
}
Query query=new Query(criteria);
```

but it gives me an exception like `Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'attribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to split these with **`$and`**? You can just do this in the regex:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "attribute": {"$regex": "^abc|^pqr|^xyz", "$options": "i" }
})
```

Not to mention that actually seems like an **`$or`** condition which is what the regex does, and you must actually want that because a string cannot possibly match all of those things from the beginning of the string, you can only ever have one.

That should translate to the springdata mongo method quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[]={"abc","pqr",xyz};

Query query = new Query();

Criteria criteria;

for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
  criteria = Criteria.where("attribute").regex("^" + splited[i], "i");
  query.addCriteria(criteria);
}
```